# How to use MySQL's standard deviation (STD, STDDEV, STDDEV_POP) function inside SQLAlchemy?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, standard-deviation

I need to use the `STD` function of MySQL through SQLAlchemy, but after a couple of minutes of search, it looks like there is no `func.<>` way of using this one in SQLAlchemy. Is it not supported, or am I missing something?

Comment: Just use it like `func.STD(...)` and sqlachemy will produce the SQL. `sa.func(...)` acts as a *generator*.

Comment: @van but I can't seem to find a `func.STD` in SQLAlchemy. Are you saying that it will work nevertheless?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue while coding some aggregates on SQLAlchemy.

Citing the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func):

> Any name can be given to **func**. If the function name is unknown to SQLAlchemy, it will be rendered exactly as is. For common SQL functions which SQLAlchemy is aware of, the name may be interpreted as a generic function which will be compiled appropriately to the target database.

Basically func will generate a function matching the attribute "func." if its not a common function of which SQLAlchemy is aware of (like func.count).

To keep the advantages of RDBMS abstraction that comes with any ORM I always suggest to use [ANSI functions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/ch04s02.html) to decouple the code from the DB Engine.

For a working sample you can add a connection string and execute the following code:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import func, create_engine, Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from sqlalchemy.types import DateTime, Integer, String

# Add your connection string
engine = create_engine('My Connection String')
Base = declarative_base(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db_session = Session()

# Make sure to have a table foo in the db with foo_id, bar, baz columns
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    __table_args__ = { 'autoload' : True }

query = db_session.query(
    func.count(Foo.bar).label('count_agg'),
    func.avg(Foo.foo_id).label('avg_agg'),
    func.stddev(Foo.foo_id).label('stddev_agg'),
    func.stddev_samp(Foo.foo_id).label('stddev_samp_agg')
)

print(query.statement.compile())
```

It will generate the following SQL

```sql
SELECT  count(foo.bar) AS count_agg, 
        avg(foo.foo_id) AS avg_agg, 
        stddev(foo.foo_id) AS stddev_agg, 
        stddev_samp(foo.foo_id) AS stddev_samp_agg
FROM foo
```